# Use Uri retrieved with Intent picker in a Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider, android-permissions, permission-denied

I am trying to pick the `URI` for a video in one `Activity`, and then use the Uri (access its contents) in a `Service`.

What I'm doing is:

1. In one Activity, pick one Uri:

```
val intent = Intent(ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
intent.type = "video/*"
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_VIDEO)
```

2. In `onActivityResult`, I get the Uri from the returned bundle:

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            when (requestCode) {
                PICK_VIDEO -> { openService(intent?.data!!) }
            }
        }
    }
```

3. Then, I open one `Service` (actually an `IntentService`) from the `Activity` straight away.
   I pass the retrieved Uri.
4. In the `Service`, I try to read the contents of the `Uri`.

```
override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        intent?.let {
            Log.i(TAG, "Uploading video.")
            // read the contents of the Uri with ContentPrrovider
        }
```

When trying to do so I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10091 does not have permission to content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F56/ORIGINAL/NONE/1281553805 [user 0]
```

How can I fix this? How could I grant permission for my `Service` (the belongs to the same app) to read the Uri?

Note that I need to `PICK` one file from the gallery. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` does not give me the desired user experience, as I just want the user to pick something form the gallery witout allowing folder navigation.

Comment: Indeed you have permision but that last not long now adays if you dont take persistable uri permission in onActivityResult() (Which you forgot to mention as step). Use getContentResolver().takePersistabletUriPermission(). Ohhh you use ACTION_PICK... better use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT for permanent permissions.

Comment: I'm afraid I need PICK, not OPEN... Anyway, I don't understand why I can't use the Uri retrieved in my Activity in a Service the Activity opens. It's not an exported Service and it belongs to my app. What if I need to upload the contents of the Uri? I need to do it from a Service to prevent the case of the Activity being destroyed.

Comment: Yes but uri read write permissions lifetime are bound to the lifetime of your activity. You could as well save uri.toString() and reopen your app and try to read from the content scheme. It will not do. But using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and taking persistable permissions you could.

Comment: You could try(untested) to add a flag grand read uri permission to the intent starting the service.

Comment: I am experiencing that the `Uri` retrieved, even with `PICK_VIDEO` has permission to be used in the requesting `Activity` *and* in the `Service` opened from the `Activity`. However, as soon as the `Activity` finishes the permission seems to be lost. If I read the `Uri` from the `Service` while the `Activity` is alive it works. As soon as the `Activity` is killed, reading the `Uri` from the `Service` throws `IllegalAccessException`. Only workaround I see is to get the `Uri` with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or create a temporary file in the cache directory with the contents of the `Uri`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from code above, but I'm guessing for the next call, you will launch some native application which can access to files, and return just link to that file.

```
val intent = Intent(ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
intent.type = "video/*"
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_VIDEO)
```

At this point of time, neither `Activity` nor `Service` has access to file. Because in the `Activity` you are working with a path only.

1) Just make sure you have proper permission [within Content Provider as mentioned int the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics#Permissions). And/or [Data Access permission within Content Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics#Intents).

Comment: I am not launching any app, I am accessing the file directly in my own Service (more specifically, I'm using ContentProvider to get the media type of the Uri)

Comment: @GaRRaPeTa It's just not described. By `Intent(ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)` I assume `ACTION_PICK` It's explicit intent.

Comment: @GaRRaPeTa In any case, check a permissions for Content Provider in the links above.

Comment: @GaRRaPeTa Did you try setting permissions above?

Comment: Yes, I did. As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58806104/use-uri-retrieved-with-intent-picker-in-a-service#comment103911129_58806104 the permissions last only as long as the `Activity` that launched the pick `Intent` is alive.